# Read state from outside of Widget

Tags: flutter

I am having trouble figuring out how to read the value of a variable in the state of a Widget from outside of that Widget. Very simply put, I need to access the rating variable from outside of the RatableListItem. I have a set of RatableListItems in another Widget that I would like to iterate over to collect the ratings.

How do I go about getting access to the state of each RatableListItem to get the rating variable out of it?

Here is a dumbed down version of the code:

```
class RatableListItem extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new RatableEmotionListItemState();

}

class RatableListItemState extends State<RatableListItem> {

   String _title = "Test";

   var _ratings = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];

   String _rating = '0';

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListTile(
    leading: new Text(_title),
    trailing: new DropdownButton<String>(

      items: _ratings.map((String rating) {
        return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: rating, child: new Text(rating));}).toList(),

    value: _rating,

    onChanged: (String value) {
        setState(() {
          _rating = value;
        });
    },

   )
);
}

String getRating() {
  return _rating;
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass a parameter function like this :

```
        class _TestingState extends State<Testing> {
          List<int> values = [0,0,0,0,0,0];

          _getData() {
            //here you have your data
            values.forEach((item) => print("value: $item"));
          }

          _rateByIndex(int index, int value) {
            values[index] = value;
          }

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return new MaterialApp(
                title: 'Flutter Demo',
                theme: new ThemeData(
                  primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
                ),
                home: Material(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: values.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return RatableListItem(rateByIndex: _rateByIndex, index: index);
                        },
                      ),
                      MaterialButton(
                        child: Text("ACTION"),
                        onPressed: _getData,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ));
          }
        }

        typedef void RateByIndex(int index, int value);

        class RatableListItem extends StatefulWidget {
          final RateByIndex rateByIndex;
          final int index;

          RatableListItem({this.index,this.rateByIndex});

          @override
          State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new RatableListItemState();
        }

        class RatableListItemState extends State<RatableListItem> {
          String _title = "Test";

          var _ratings = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];

          String _rating = '0';

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return new ListTile(
                leading: new Text(_title),
                trailing: new DropdownButton<String>(
                  items: _ratings.map((String rating) {
                    return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: rating, child: new Text(rating));
                  }).toList(),
                  value: _rating,
                  onChanged: (String value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _rating = value;
                    });
                    widget.rateByIndex(widget.index, int.parse(value));
                  },
                ));
          }

          String getRating() {
            return _rating;
          }

          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
          }

          @override
          void dispose() {
            super.dispose();
          }
        }
```

I'm initializing the values List in the global declaration, you can modify that.
When you press the ACTION button, you will get all the values.

The parameter function will receive index of the item, and value of each item.
You will use the List values to store all of the values from your items.